# Open a downloaded JAR file Mac with Java code

Tags: java, macos, executable-jar

I am creating a simple download program that opens a file with the web browser to download it.  On Mac, there is a dialog when you open a downloaded executable JAR file that says you
[can't open it because it is from an unidentified developer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1V3E.png).
Is there a way to open the JAR file without the dialog by using Java code?  Here is my code:

```
            File newFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.home")+"/Library/AppTest/Application.jar");
            File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.home")+"/Downloads/AppTest.jar");
            try {
                Files.move(file.toPath(), newFile.toPath());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

The problem with the code is when it executes, it just [shows this dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1V3E.png), and will not let you open the file.  I want to fix this without having to go to settings, because other users may have the same problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "open"? Are you trying to get the OS to _execute_ the file?  That is not likely to work.

Comment: You need to go into your settings, and change it from "only App Store apps" to "all apps/ unidentified developers."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open a JAR file on a mac, use `Runtime`:

```
String command = "java -jar path/to/jar/file";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

the above code is from [this link](https://crunchify.com/how-to-run-windowsmac-commands-in-java-and-return-the-text-result/).